# Unable to call method in another component in React Native "null is not an object"

Tags: react-native

I have a snack setup (please ignore the styling):

https://snack.expo.io/@drc83/view-not-scrolling

Click show modal -> click Next Button. On the slider page when clicking an image, the View should change (slide horizontally to the next view) but I get an error "null is not an object". The problem lies in SliderEntry.js,

```
this.MyScrollView.current.moveToPage(3);
```

How can I call this moveToPage method from within the SliderEntry file?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `ref` the right way.
On your ScrollView component, set `ref` to this:

```
<MyScrollView ref={(ref) => { this.MyScrollView = ref; }}>
```

You should also bind your `nextView` to your `Component`, otherwise `this` will be always null inside that function (since it is executed after the Component has been rendered):

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isModalVisible: false
  }

  this.nextView = this.nextView.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestions (and variations without success). Could you advise what might be wrong, in case I missed something. (please note that originally the nextView method was working, it was the select method in SliderEntry.js that was not) Thanks